# Como fazer com que a propriedade "mix-blend-mode" do CSS funcione no Internet Explorer e no Edge?

Tags: css, css3

Fiz uma camada degradê que vai por cima de algumas imagens no meu projeto com o seguinte código CSS:

```
{
     background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(32, 51, 108, 1), rgba(237, 17, 100, 1));
     mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente em todos os navegadores, com exceção do Edge e do Internet Explorer. Saberiam me dizer se existe alguma alternativa?

**OBS.:** A minha primeira alternativa foi apesar reduzir a opacidade do elemento, porém, não me retorna o mesmo efeito que está no design.

Comment: relacionada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407846/css-blend-mode-not-working

Comment: @marquinho esse pergunta não tem nada de relacionada com a outra... além do link que vc indicou estar em ingles, lá eles nem tocam no assunto de Internet Explorer ou Edge, não tem nada a ver esse link e só confunde os outros usuários

Comment: @marquinho são problemas distintos, no caso da pergunta acima o blend mode não estava funcionando por conta de erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Matheus vc já conferiu no Google analytics quantos % do seu público usa IE? Duvido que vc precise dar suporte a ele... mas no caso do Edge a próxima atualização dele vai usar o Chromium, o mesmo do Chrome, então ele vai passar a aceitar praticamente tudo que o chrome aceita

Comment: Tá sim! ele não colocou o seletor e não vai funcionar os estilos.

Comment: @marquinho você leu o enunciado da pergunta? **O código está funcionando perfeitamente em todos os navegadores** com exceção do IE e do Edge. Não é um erro de sintaxe da minha parte, e sim um problema de compatibilidade dos navegadores da Microsoft. Minha dúvida não é se está funcionando ou não, e sim como rodar essa propriedade nesses navegadores

Comment: @hugocsl o site é para a agência que eu trabalho, e alguns dos clientes utilizam muito o IE ainda, por conta disso o projeto precisa rodar nele também.

Comment: Paara um user que ja tem mais de 6 anos de Stackoverflow, posso dizer que esta pergunta está mal fechada. https://stackoverflow.com/users/3448527/dippas, Está complemente dentro do escopo pois esta a pedir uma solucao para uma properiedade de CSS para um browser como o IE

Comment: @dippas infelizmente isso acontece com frequência, queria saber o motivo.

Answer (score 1):

De momento o `mix-blend-mode` não é suportado pelo IE, veja aqui no [canIuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_mix-blend-mode)

[image: SS]

Comment: Sim @dippas, estou ciente. O que eu gostaria de saber é se existe alguma alternativa para fazer um efeito semelhante com css ou quem sabe alguma lib em js que possa resolver o problema.

Comment: podes usar `::after` e tentar ajustar a `opacity` mas nunca vai ficar 100%